# Button action is not called on UIViewController added on Paging

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, paging

I'm making one application in which I had added four class on childView

```
[self addChildViewController:homeScreenViewController];
[self addChildViewController:portFolioViewController];
[self addChildViewController:watchListViewController];
[self addChildViewController:marketingViewController];
```

Than I call the childView on pageControl as paging.
Now on the homeScreenViewController Class I have added a button but the button do not take any action.

I have declare button like this in HomeScreenViewController class. Here is the code

```
btn_Trade                 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn_Trade.frame           = CGRectMake(0.0, 150.0, 142.0, 40.0);
    [btn_Trade setTitle:@"TRADE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_Trade setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    btn_Trade.titleLabel.font  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-Light" size:20.0];
    [btn_Trade setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [btn_Trade setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_Trade addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToTradeListViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn_Trade setEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:btn_Trade];
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: We need to see code from where you add the button and set its target action.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code of your pushToTradeListViewController method please ?

BTW, if your pushToTradeListViewController looks like that :

```
-(void)pushToTradeListViewController:(id)sender{    
....
}
```

you need to add `:` (2 points) after your method name in your selector, like this :

```
[btn_Trade addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToTradeListViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```